# Show more than 10 calls in Codeception stack trace

Tags: codeception

I'm debugging some recursive code via Codeception and it's only showing the last 10 calls, so I don't know what the path through the code is. Xdebug is set to show as much information as possible so, I don't think it's that.

I haven't yet found any configuration option to increase the number of stack trace levels show in Codeception's output.

How can I increase the number of calls in Codeception's output?

Truncated error message:

```
There was 1 error:

---------
1) Hl7MessageHeaderSegmentWriterTest: Should build a message header segment
 Test  tests\unit\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Segment\Hl7MessageHeaderSegmentWriterTest.php:testShouldBuildAMessageHeaderSegment

  [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Object of class DateTimeImmutable could not be converted to string

#1  Codeception\Subscriber\ErrorHandler->errorHandler
#2  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7ElementFormatter.php:283
#3  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7ElementFormatter.php:251
#4  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7SimpleElementWriter.php:49
#5  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7ElementFormatter.php:54
#6  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7ElementFormatter.php:29
#7  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7ElementFormatter.php:54
#8  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7ElementFormatter.php:29
#9  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7ElementFormatter.php:54
#10 C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Segment\Hl7HeaderSegmentWriter.php:18

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Normal error message (note the last line is the entry point from codecept.phar):

```
There was 1 error:

---------
1) Hl7MessageHeaderSegmentWriterTest: Should build a message header segment
 Test  tests\unit\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Segment\Hl7MessageHeaderSegmentWriterTest.php:testShouldBuildAMessageHeaderSegment

  [Exception] foo

#1  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Data\Hl7DateTimeWrapperDataWriter.php:45
#2  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Data\Hl7TimeStampDataWriter.php:54
#3  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7DataForwarder.php:30
#4  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7DataForwarder.php:24
#5  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7DataForwarder.php:20
#6  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\src\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7DataForwarder.php:13
#7  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\tests\unit\HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Segment\Hl7MessageHeaderSegmentWriterTest.php:53
#8  HMRX\CoreBundle\Utils\Hl7Writer\Hl7MessageHeaderSegmentWriterTest->testShouldBuildAMessageHeaderSegment
#9  C:\usr\bin\codecept.phar:7

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Xdebug config from phpinfo():

```
xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.5.5

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => \ => \
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => \ => \
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => -1 => -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data => -1 => -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => -1 => -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run codeception with `-vvv` flag to get a full stacktrace.

Comment: This works, but it would be nice to have an in-between option that doesn't show the phar calls.

Comment: `-vvv` doesn't work for me. The stack trace is still limited to 10.

Comment: -vvv did work for me, and it removed the #1, ... #10 prefixes in the output. Make sure you get the parameter in the right place?  `codecept -vvv run unit tests/src/...` There are 16 frames before it gets to my test class.

Comment: Note `--debug` overrides `-vvv` https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4989

Answer (score 0):

The number `$limit = 10` is hard-coded in `\Codeception\Subscriber\Console::printExceptionTrace`

you could temporarily edit that number to be slightly higher.

The `$this->rawStackTrace` is the codeception flag which is set from the `-vvv` Symfony Console parameter, and which bypasses the limited rendering loop and just dumps the raw stack trace.

Both of them also skip the filtered classes defined in `\PHPUnit\Util\Filter::$filteredClassesPattern` so you could add more classes to that array to remove the application stuff (if that's what you mean by the phar calls, I'm not using a phar, I'm using it via composer which is simpler to edit).